# Find the time it takes for a particle to be traveling perpendicular to original projection

Tags: vectors, classical-mechanics

I received this question in my recent homework and don't know how to approach it:
"A particle is projected from a height of 30m above the ground, with initial velocity 3i+4j. Find the time it takes for a particle to be traveling perpendicular to original projection"

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is unclear.  Is there gravity?  If so, what is the acceleration due to gravity?

Comment: @BrianTung Accel is 9.8 under gravity, sorry i forgot to specify. This is a A2 level question (UK), if that makes a difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that gravity does not affect horizontal velocity, so that when the conditions of the question are satisfied, the projectile velocity will be $3i+aj$, where $a$ needs to be determined.  The easiest way to do so is to note that the dot product of two perpendicular non-zero vectors is zero; in this case, it tells us that

$$
(3, 4) \cdot (3, a) = 3 \times 3 + 4 \times a = 0
$$

Simple algebra tells us what $a$ is, and then the time it takes to do so is given by

$$
t = \frac{4-a}{9.8}
$$

where the $4$ comes from the initial vertical component of velocity.  The only relevance of the $30$ m initial height that I can see is the determination of whether the projectile *ever* travels perpendicular to its original vector, or if it hits the ground first.  But in this case, I think you should be able to verify, fairly easily, that it does not hit the ground first (provided the ground is level).

Comment: Thanks for the help. Very well explained